# Google Map Polyline Arrays from XML

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, polyline

In my javascript code,every x seconds, I get a variable 'polys' from a XML ,with indefinite number of pairs of coordinates, as this(I have omitted some variables): echo.php

```
<markers>
<marker iph="ce987" polys="[40.66645296,-0.22793904],[39.66973274,0.21806265]"/>
</markers>
```

Javascript code:

```
        function processXML(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        //clear markers before you start drawing new ones
        resetMarkers(markersArray)
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var idp = markers[i].getAttribute("idp");
            var polys = markers[i].getAttribute("polys");

            var genpolys = [];

            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: genpolys,
              geodesic: true,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              map: map
            });

            markersArray.push(marker);
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            downloadUrl("echo.php", processXML);
        }, 19000);
    }
```

And, I need generate an ¿array? with the coordenates, like this:

```
var genpolys = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.66645296,-0.22793904),
    new google.maps.LatLng(39.66973274,0.21806265)
  ];
```

My level of javascript is too low, so I don't know generate this variable automatically indefinite number of pairs of coordinates.Then use in 'path' inside the 'Polyline'

Could someone help me out here? Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. (I know it's not exactly right, but might give you an idea. I will try to edit later.)

```
function processXML(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    //clear markers before you start drawing new ones
    resetMarkers(markersArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var idp = markers[i].getAttribute("idp");
        var polys = markers[i].getAttribute("polys");

        var genpolys = [];
        var json = JSON.parse('{"polys":['+polys+']}');
        for(var coord in json.polys){
            genpolys[coord] = new google.maps.LatLng(json.polys[coord][0],json.polys[coord][1]);    
        }

        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: genpolys,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        map: map
        });

        markersArray.push(marker);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        downloadUrl("echo.php", processXML);
    }, 19000);
}
```

I hope this helps you figure it out. I adapted the answer from this page: [how to draw polylines on google maps dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594040/how-to-draw-polylines-on-google-maps-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks @JordanPowell for your quick answer !!, still not working. I put alert(point); and alert(geopolys); and I get 'NaN'

Comment: There is an error in the code I have written that will prevent the LatLng objects from being created. I'll try to make it better when I am available. In the meantime see if you get anywhere with this: http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/263/ @VictorCormano

Comment: This should do that unless I misunderstand your intent. I understood you to mean that for each <marker /> XML tag, there could be any number of coordinate pairs in the polys attribute. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/265/ When run, four pairs of coordinates are used.

Comment: Yes @JordanPowell, works, but now I found that the 'script' is not updated automatically, (without the funtion setTimeout). I need to press F5 manual for update the position of the object and the trace ¿?

Comment: @VictorCormano you need to add the timeout (actually change this to interval) with the `downloadUrl` back in. See edits here: http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/266

Comment: @VictorCormano It sounds like your original issue has been solved. Please upvote and select my answer. You may want to create a new question for the remaining problem so users with more expertise will be likely to see it.